# UIRefreshControl & UiTableview Content Inset

Tags: ios, swift, refresh

While using `UIRefresherControl` in a `UITableView`, when the content insets of the table view is 0 everything works fine, and the refresh starts when you pull up, and the content offset of the scroll view reaches to approximately -200.

However when I set the content inset of the `UITableView` to -176 (that I need to do), when I pull up until -376, the refresh is still not starting. Enabling or disabling the "Adjust Scroll View Insets" setting is not making any change. What can I do, should I also change any content inset value of `UIRefresherControl` in someway? Or isn't it adjusting automatically when you change the content inset of the `UITableView`?

```
var refresher:UIRefreshControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

refresher = UIRefreshControl()
refresher.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents:    UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
self.resultsTable.addSubview(refresher)

 }


  func refresh() {

  print("refresh table")

  refreshTable()

  }
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. Changing tableview's content inset dynamically messes with the refresh control.

The root cause is that refresh control changes the content offset and in turn calls scrollViewDidScroll (which is where the content inset was reset)

Solution 1. 
If you are only setting content inset once (so when the controller loads), set it via the storyboard.

Solution 2. 
If content inset needs to be set dynamically during scroll view delegate methods. Try something like this:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    if offset >= -tableViewInsetHeight {

        // Change contentInset only if contentoffset is 
        // greater than the inset 
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-offset, 0, 0, 0)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger on any offset you want if trigger the event on the `scrollViewDidEndDragging` method of the UITableView's delegate:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) 
{
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= -60
    {
        refresher.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }
}
```

In this case Im setting it to trigger to 60.